# How to expand from contacts to customer

Tags: odata, erp, dynamics-business-central

I'm getting the following error (The endpoint is included in the error):

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 id type not specified. returned for "https://.../v1.0/companies(5d48aae4-56ab-ec11-8732-cebd1c770568)/contacts?$filter=id+eq+c1efba57-331f-ee11-8d04-9198766618fc&$expand=contactInformation
  er%29".
```

But I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, for example `picture` does expand as expected. I have the following mapping documentation:

```
<EntityType Name="contact">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="id"/>
  </Key>
  <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="number" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20"/>
  <Property Name="type" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="displayName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100"/>
  <Property Name="companyNumber" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20"/>
  <Property Name="companyName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100"/>
  <Property Name="businessRelation" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="50"/>
  <Property Name="contactBusinessRelation" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="addressLine1" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100"/>
  <Property Name="addressLine2" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="50"/>
  <Property Name="city" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30"/>
  <Property Name="state" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30"/>
  <Property Name="country" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="10"/>
  <Property Name="postalCode" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20"/>
  <Property Name="phoneNumber" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30"/>
  <Property Name="mobilePhoneNumber" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30"/>
  <Property Name="email" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="80"/>
  <Property Name="website" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="80"/>
  <Property Name="searchName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100"/>
  <Property Name="privacyBlocked" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
  <Property Name="taxRegistrationNumber" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="lastInteractionDate" Type="Edm.Date"/>
  <Property Name="lastModifiedDateTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="picture" Type="Microsoft.NAV.picture" Partner="contact" ContainsTarget="true">
    <ReferentialConstraint Property="id" ReferencedProperty="id"/>
  </NavigationProperty>
  <NavigationProperty Name="contactInformation" Type="Microsoft.NAV.contactInformation" Partner="contact" ContainsTarget="true">
    <ReferentialConstraint Property="id" ReferencedProperty="contactId"/>
  </NavigationProperty>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="contactInformation">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="contactId"/>
  </Key>
  <Property Name="contactId" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="contactNumber" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="20"/>
  <Property Name="contactName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="100"/>
  <Property Name="contactType" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="relatedId" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="relatedType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="customer" Type="Microsoft.NAV.customer" Partner="contactsInformation" ContainsTarget="true">
    <ReferentialConstraint Property="relatedId" ReferencedProperty="id"/>
  </NavigationProperty>
  <NavigationProperty Name="contact" Type="Microsoft.NAV.contact" Partner="contactInformation" ContainsTarget="true">
    <ReferentialConstraint Property="contactId" ReferencedProperty="id"/>
  </NavigationProperty>
</EntityType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats the Filter for?

In the Base App from Microsoft, there's no field called "id". Maybe you are looking for No.?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).